# Having trouble getting xml to indent properly with pretty_print

Tags: python, xml

I've got a program that's working as desired for the most part. It's taking information from an excel file and creating an xml. The last issue is that I can't get the indents just right.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ETXML
import lxml.etree as etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import shutil
import os
import sys
import codecs
from xml.dom import minidom

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
VARINFO = pd.read_excel(open('Input.xlsx', 'rb'),"VAR_INFO")
VALINFO = pd.read_excel(open('Input.xlsx', 'rb'),"VAL_INFO")


df2=VARINFO.copy()
df2=df2.drop(df2[df2.column_tables == 0].index)

df3=VALINFO.copy()
df3=df3.drop(df3[df3.column_var == 0].index)

df4=VARINFO.copy()
df4=df4.drop(df4[df4.row_tables == 0].index)

df5=VALINFO.copy()
df5=df5.drop(df5[df5.row_var == 0].index)

root = ETXML.Element("paramname", version="1.0", createdBy="PowerStats v1.0")    # Create root element
columns = ETXML.SubElement(root, "columns")
rows = ETXML.SubElement(root, "rows")
component = ETXML.SubElement(columns, "component")
rcomponent = ETXML.SubElement(rows, "component")
element = ETXML.SubElement(component, "element")




def colcmp(row, x):
    colxml = ETXML.SubElement(component, "component", label=str(VARINFO.var_label.unique().tolist()[x]), varname=str(VARINFO.var_name.unique().tolist()[x]), format="DISC", missingValue="-3", tag="tag" )
    newDF = df3.loc[df3.var_name == row]
    val_label = newDF.val_label.tolist()
    element = ETXML.SubElement(component, "element")
    for i in range(len(val_label)):
         rowinfo = ETXML.SubElement(element, "element", label=str(newDF.val_label.tolist()[i]), varname=str(newDF.var_name.tolist()[i]), format="DISC", missingValue="-3", tag="tag" )

def rowcmp(row, x):   
    rowxml = ETXML.SubElement(rcomponent, "component", label=str(df4.var_label.unique().tolist()[x]), varname=str(df4.var_name.unique().tolist()[x]), format="DISC", missingValue="-3", tag="tag" )
    newDFR = df5.loc[df5.var_name == row]
    val_label = newDFR.val_label.tolist()
    relement = ETXML.SubElement(rcomponent, "element")
    for i in range(len(val_label)):
         rinfo = ETXML.SubElement(relement, "element", label=str(newDFR.val_label.tolist()[i]), varname=str(newDFR.var_name.tolist()[i]), format="DISC", missingValue="-3", tag="tag" )

list1 = df2.var_name.tolist()
list2 = df3.var_name.tolist()
list3 = df4.var_name.tolist()
list4 = df5.var_name.tolist()

for rows in range (len(list1)):
    rowinfo = colcmp(list1[rows], rows)

for rows in range (len(list3)):
    rinfo = rowcmp(list3[rows], rows)

rootWrite = ETXML.ElementTree(root)
rootWrite.write("createXml.txt")

with open(r'createXml.txt', 'r') as infile, \
     open(r'createXml2.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    data = infile.read()
    data = data.replace("<component>", "")
    data = data.replace("<element>", "")
    data = data.replace("</component>", "")
    data = data.replace("</element>", "")
    data = data.replace("<element />", "")
    outfile.write(data)



xmlstr = minidom.parse("createXml2.xml").toprettyxml(indent="   ")
with open("createXml2.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)

print(xmlstr)
```

The only problem, is that the resulting XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<paramname createdBy="PowerStats v1.0" version="1.0">
   <columns>
      <component format="fmat" label="varlabel1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
      <component format="fmat" label="varlabel2" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item2" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item3" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
      <element format="fmat" label="item4" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
   </columns>
</paramname>
```

When, what I actually need is:
The only problem, is that the resulting XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<paramname createdBy="PowerStats v1.0" version="1.0">
   <columns>
      <component format="fmat" label="varlabel1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var1"/>
      <component format="fmat" label="varlabel2" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item1" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item2" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item3" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
          <element format="fmat" label="item4" missingValue="-3" tag="tag" varname="var2"/>
   </columns>
</paramname>
```

The element should be a sub-element of component, but pretty-print doesn't seem to be treating it that way. I can't tell if I'm declaring incorrectly somewhere in the program, or if there's some kind of limit on the number of identions with pretty_print. I'm not extremely experienced with cElementTree/ElementTree. Any help at all would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: In your code is no pprint?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: If `element` should be a child of `component` but actually isn't, then that is not a problem with pretty-printing; it is a problem in the logic of the code. Your code contains a lot of stuff that seems unnecessary to demonstrate the problem. Please trim the code down and provide a [mcve].